# How can I tidy up grout lines 24 hours later?

Tags: tile, cleaning, grout

My first ever grouting work yesterday went okay, but I rushed through in a bit of a panic as I am new to this.

In the light of the next day I'm not entirely happy with the cleanliness of the grout lines -- they are up over the bevel in a lot of places, and I don't mind spending another couple of hours tidying them up a little.

I grouted yesterday from 6-9 PM; as of this morning the grout is still soft enough that I can chip away at little ugly bits with my thumbnail. I'm at work now and will be getting home around 5 PM with the evening free.

1. Am I being too hard on myself and this looks fine?
2. If I can improve these lines, what's the best method? Is there a tool I'm likely to have at home that could help scrape out the bevels but keep the grout between the tiles intact? The challenge here is I'm carless and distant from any hardware stores.
3. Are there any problems that could come up if I try to clean up the grout lines to be a bit more matching the bevel of the titles?

[image: Grout lines over bevel of tile]

Comment: It took some looking to see what you were talking about. Over all, I think you've done a good job, especially for your first go at it. I can see your desire to clean it up, though. :) I'm far from the expert, so I can't really offer advice, just encouragement.

Comment: Not bad for a first timer, as with most stuff you get better with practice.  Grout gets hard fast and gets harder to remove.  Will need to be careful not to damage the tile surface so soft plastic tools unless very careful with metal.  Will depend on how perfect you want it, but looks good.

Comment: The "best method" would have been more time with a sponge last night, unfortunately. Now it will be getting increasingly difficult.

Comment: Thanks -- and I agree, @Ecnerwal, but my first time out of the gate I was paranoid that too much sponging would force water into the grout lines themselves... maybe I can take the "this looks okay" from the above commenters and just chill out a bit :)

Comment: It is, indeed, quite decent for your first time. As for the sponging, you wring it out throughly (and wash it, A LOT, as the process goes on.) It should not be adding water, just wiping excess grout. Damp, not wet.

Comment: You can try scraping it with a plastic spoon.

Comment: Im just chiming in to say you did a good job especially being your first time. I wouldnt bother to me in looks good .

Answer (score 8):

The one method I've had the best luck with is using a single edged utility blade and skimming over the tile/excess grout toward the grout lines. This will clean/scrape out the excess grout but not score/scratch the tile.

Looks like a pretty good job to me.

Comment: I agree with Jack but the best thing is a plastic razor blade, they dull quickly but will not scratch or cut excessively deep. +

Answer (score 2):

I have used a wood chop stick (the thicker end) with success.

Answer (score 1):

You could chase it all with the 'square' end of a round [or small half round] file… gently. Though the grout is dry, it will still be fairly soft. You're not filing it, so much as just dragging the corner across the grout using the tile edges as your guide & depth gauge.

[image]

<sup>can't find a good pic of a full round file</sup>

Any marks the file may make on the tiles - so long as they are not actual scratches - can be removed with a wet melamine sponge.

As already mentioned in comments, this isn't bad at all for a first attempt, and like all decorating irregularities, after 6 weeks you'll forget it wasn't perfect; you'll just stop noticing.

Comment: I would not use a file it will scratch the glaze, a plastic tool to lightly scrape it is all that should be used at this point.